# PHP PDO fetchObject() - object containing only default values except id member

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to fetch an object from a MySQL database, which has a table called 'Article'. The getLatestArticle() function is as following:

```
public function getLatestArticle($priority){
    $query = "select * from article where priority = :priority having date = max(date);";
    $STH = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
    $STH->bindParam(':priority', $priority);

    if(!$STH->execute()){
        print_r($STH->errorInfo());
    }else{
        return $STH->fetchObject('Article');
    }
}
```

Having included the classes properly, and having the names of class variables, constructor parameters and column names in mysql identical produces this:

```
object(Article)#6 (8) { ["id":"Article":private]=> string(2) "13" ["title":"Article":private]=> string(0) "" ["subTitle":"Article":private]=> string(0) "" ["imgFilePath":"Article":private]=> string(0) "" ["contentFilePath":"Article":private]=> string(0) "" ["author":"Article":private]=> string(0) "" ["date":"Article":private]=> string(0) "" ["priority":"Article":private]=> string(0) "" }
```

I get an object of the class Article as expected, although only the field 'id' is correct while all the others are using default values. 
I tried using setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ, 'Article') and using fetch(), also tried using setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Article) and using fetch() without any luck.
All the class variables in Article are specified as private and the constructor is presented like so:

```
public function __construct($title="", $subTitle="", $imgFilePath="", $contentFilePath="", $author="", $date="", $priority = ""){
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->subTitle = $subTitle;
    $this->imgFilePath = $imgFilePath;
    $this->contentFilePath = $contentFilePath;
    $this->author = $author;
    $this->date = $date;
    $this->priority = $priority;
}
```

I tried removing the default values in the constructor and changing the class members from private to public, produces a missing argument error.

Why do objects retrieved through fetchObject('Article') end up with only the id field with a correct value while all other fields use the default value?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, fetching an associative array will have all the fields filled correctly, but i would like to do it with fetchObject()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will skip question 1, because you start with question 2, and one question is enough. You don't show all the code involved, so I have to make guesses.

I have noted in the PHP manual that it says: **"When an object is fetched, its properties are assigned from respective column values, and afterwards its constructor is invoked."**. So you when your constructor is:

```
class Article
{
  public function __construct($title="", $subTitle="", $imgFilePath="",
                              $contentFilePath="", $author="", 
                              $date="", $priority = "") {
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->subTitle = $subTitle;
    $this->imgFilePath = $imgFilePath;
    $this->contentFilePath = $contentFilePath;
    $this->author = $author;
    $this->date = $date;
    $this->priority = $priority;
  }
}
```

The constructor will overwrite the column values retrieved with `PDOStatement::fetchObject`.

To do it correctly use this:

```
class Article
{
  private $title = '';
  private $subTitle = '';
  private $imgFilePath = '';
  private $contentFilePath = '';
  private $author = '';
  private $date = '';
  private $priority = '';

  public function __construct() {
    // do whatever you need, but do not overwrite the column values
  }
}
```

I hope this helps. If you have to set 'column values' you can use setters in the class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer :)